# ''Technique manuals'' recommendation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

In my studying of generating functions I got hold of [this article](http://web.mit.edu/~qchu/Public/TopicsInGF.pdf) and I liked it very much.
Why?

It's concise, does a good job of introducing you to the main ideas and shows a lot of uses of this particular technique (some of them unexpected).
I finished it thinking: Wow, I'm really glad I know this now!

I was wondering are there some other articles of this type floating around the internet? Introducing you to a particular problem-solving technique with interesting examples and problems. Maybe even whole books in that style?

Comment: A [certain member](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/) of MSE is going to be very flattered...

Comment: That was for WOOT, right? There'll be other WOOT articles around